# How to extract RSS links from website with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, rss

I am trying to extract all RSS feed links from some websites. Ofc if RSS exists. These are some website links that have RSS, and below is list of RSS links from those websites.

```
website_links = ["https://www.diepresse.com/", 
"https://www.sueddeutsche.de/", 
"https://www.berliner-zeitung.de/", 
"https://www.aargauerzeitung.ch/", 
"https://www.luzernerzeitung.ch/", 
"https://www.nzz.ch/",
"https://www.spiegel.de/", 
"https://www.blick.ch/",
"https://www.berliner-zeitung.de/", 
"https://www.ostsee-zeitung.de/", 
"https://www.kleinezeitung.at/", 
"https://www.blick.ch/", 
"https://www.ksta.de/", 
"https://www.tagblatt.ch/", 
"https://www.srf.ch/", 
"https://www.derstandard.at/"]


website_rss_links = ["https://www.diepresse.com/rss/Kunst", 
"https://rss.sueddeutsche.de/rss/Kultur", 
"https://www.berliner-zeitung.de/feed.id_kultur-kunst.xml", 
"https://www.aargauerzeitung.ch/leben-kultur.rss", 
"https://www.luzernerzeitung.ch/kultur.rss", 
"https://www.nzz.ch/technologie.rss", 
"https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/literatur/index.rss", 
"https://www.luzernerzeitung.ch/wirtschaft.rss", 
"https://www.blick.ch/wirtschaft/rss.xml", 
"https://www.berliner-zeitung.de/feed.id_abgeordnetenhauswahl.xml", 
"https://www.ostsee-zeitung.de/arc/outboundfeeds/rss/category/wissen/", 
"https://www.kleinezeitung.at/rss/politik", 
"https://www.blick.ch/wirtschaft/rss.xml", 
"https://feed.ksta.de/feed/rss/politik/index.rss", 
"https://www.tagblatt.ch/wirtschaft.rss", 
"https://www.srf.ch/news/bnf/rss/1926", 
"https://www.derstandard.at/rss/wirtschaft"]
```

My approach is to extract all links, and then check if some of them has RSS in them, but that is just a first step:

```
for url in all_links:
    
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(response)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    list_of_links = soup.select("a[href]")
    list_of_links = [link["href"] for link in list_of_links]
    print("Number of links", len(list_of_links))
 

    for l in list_of_links:
        if "rss" in l:
            print(url)
            print(l)
    print()
```

I have heard that I can look for RSS links like this, but I do not know how to incorporate this in my code.

```
type=application/rss+xml
```

My goal is to get working RSS urls at the end. Maybe it is an issue because I am sending request on the first page, and maybe I should crawl different pages in order to extract all RSS Links, but I hope that there is a faster/better way for RSS extraction.

You can see that RSS links have or end up with (for example):

```
.rss
/rss
/rss/
rss.xml
/feed/
rss-feed
```

etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, there are many curated [directories](https://www.rss-verzeichnis.de/freizeit-unterhaltung-und-bekleidung/kultur-und-kunst) and collections that can serve you well and give you a nice introduction.

However, to follow your approach, you should first collect all the links on the page that could point to an rss feed:

```
soup.select('a[href*="rss"],a[href*="/feed"],a:-soup-contains-own("RSS")')
```

and then verify again whether it is one or just a collection page:

```
soup.select('[type="application/rss+xml"],a[href*=".rss"]')
```

or checking the `content-type`:

```
if 'xml' in requests.get(rss).headers.get('content-type'):
```

**Note:** *This is just to point in a direction, cause there a lot of pattern that are used to mark such feeds - rss, feed, feed/, news, xml,... and also the `content-type` is provided differently by servers*

##### Example

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

website_links = ["https://www.diepresse.com/", 
"https://www.sueddeutsche.de/", 
"https://www.berliner-zeitung.de/", 
"https://www.aargauerzeitung.ch/", 
"https://www.luzernerzeitung.ch/", 
"https://www.nzz.ch/technologie/",
"https://www.spiegel.de/", 
"https://www.blick.ch/wirtschaft/"]

rss_feeds = []

def check_for_real_rss(url):
    base_url = re.search('^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+)',url).group(0)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    for e in soup.select('[type="application/rss+xml"],a[href*=".rss"],a[href$="feed"]'):
        if e.get('href').startswith('/'):
            rss = (base_url+e.get('href'))
        else:
            rss = (e.get('href'))
        if 'xml' in requests.get(rss).headers.get('content-type'):
            rss_feeds.append(rss)

for url in website_links:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)
    for e in soup.select('a[href*="rss"],a[href*="/feed"],a:-soup-contains-own("RSS")'):
        if e.get('href').startswith('/'):
            check_for_real_rss(url.strip('/')+e.get('href'))
        else:
            check_for_real_rss(e.get('href'))
set(rss_feeds)
```

##### Output

```
{'https://rss.sueddeutsche.de/app/service/rss/alles/index.rss?output=rss','https://rss.sueddeutsche.de/rss/Topthemen',
 'https://www.aargauerzeitung.ch/aargau/aarau.rss',
 'https://www.aargauerzeitung.ch/aargau/baden.rss',
 'https://www.aargauerzeitung.ch/leben-kultur.rss',
 'https://www.aargauerzeitung.ch/schweiz-welt.rss',
 'https://www.aargauerzeitung.ch/sport.rss',
 'https://www.bzbasel.ch/basel.rss',
 'https://www.grenchnertagblatt.ch/solothurn/grenchen.rss',
 'https://www.jetzt.de/alle_artikel.rss',
 'https://www.limmattalerzeitung.ch/limmattal.rss',
 'https://www.luzernerzeitung.ch/international.rss',
 'https://www.luzernerzeitung.ch/kultur.rss',
 'https://www.luzernerzeitung.ch/leben.rss',
 'https://www.luzernerzeitung.ch/leben/ratgeber.rss',...}
```

Comment: One question, I think that your answer gives good results only if RSS link ends with .rss, but that does not have to be the case. I have updated the question, please check it out.

Comment: Also, your first 2 lines of code are soup.select(...) with two different parameters, can you tell me what should I use

Comment: The fact that there are many variations with regard to the RSS links is exactly what my note in the answer says. furthermore, I can only point in a direction and no one here will provide a complete solution. To learn more about `css selectors` take a read :https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors wich one to use is up to you and your specific needs.

Comment: Also, I can not replicate your output

Comment: If something can't be reconstructed, just be constructive and provide details to work with, as everyone can benefit from it - would be great. Given that the content of news sites can naturally change, outputs should only be considered snapshots.

Comment: I am getting the error because code extracts some email address instead of link, I can not get RSS links for luzernerzeitung.ch, it returns empty list.

Comment: Are you using the lastet version of the example? It do not exclude mail addresses per se,but doesn't collect one for given urls. Feel free, make adjustments and you will have to all the time,cause crawling is a process not a fixed state.`luzernerzeitung.ch` is not a valid url whereas `https://www.luzernerzeitung.ch` is.  Simplify and debug-Use only this single url and print `response`/`soup`/`selection` to get an idea what might happen requesting from your location. You may have to deal with blocking, captcha, cloudflare,...but this would run out of question scope. Copy example and run again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250528/discussion-between-hedgehog-and-taga).

Answer (score 0):

search for  `type="application/rss+xml"` links

like

```
<link href="/feeds" rel="alternate" title="RSS feed" type="application/rss+xml">

<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="DER SPIEGEL | RSS Schlagzeilen" href="https://www.spiegel.de/schlagzeilen/index.rss">

<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="DER SPIEGEL | RSS Nachrichten" href="https://www.spiegel.de/index.rss">
```