# Python: best way to check for list of URLs

Tags: python, unit-testing, rss

I have a file defining a list of RSS feeds:

```
RSS_FEEDS = [
    "https://www.fanpage.it/feed/",
    "https://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/feed/",
    "https://forbes.it/feed/",
    "https://formiche.net/feed/",
]
```

I wrote the following test:

```
import requests

from feeds import RSS_FEEDS

for rssfeed in RSS_FEEDS:
    response = requests.get(rssfeed)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

Are there more efficient (download less stuff) ways?

How would you handle a slow response vs a dead link?

The above would just tell me if the URL is fetchable, but how could I assess if it's a valid RSS stream?

Comment: You could speed up your requests by using multithreading. And for slow response/dead link you could add a timeout and retry loop. For rss validity try checking the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74796947/how-to-extract-rss-links-from-website-with-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it using the aiohttp library also together with asyncio, like this:

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from asyncio import gather, create_task, run, set_event_loop, set_event_loop_policy
from traceback import format_exc
import sys

# This is necessary on my Windows computer
if sys.version_info[0] == 3 and sys.version_info[1] >= 8 and sys.platform.startswith('win'): # Check for operating system
    from asyncio import ProactorEventLoop, WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy
    set_event_loop(ProactorEventLoop())
    set_event_loop_policy(WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy()) # Bug is not present in Linux

RSS_FEEDS = [
    "https://www.fanpage.it/feed/",
    "https://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/feed/",
    "https://forbes.it/feed/",
    "https://formiche.net/feed/",
]

async def GetRessource(url: str, session: ClientSession) -> dict:
    try:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                return(response.status)
            else:
                r: str = await response.text()
                print(f"Error, got response code: {response.status} message: {r}")
    except Exception:
        print(f"General Exception:\n{format_exc()}")
    return({})

async def GetUrls() -> None:
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        Tasks: list = [create_task(GetRessource(url, session)) for url in RSS_FEEDS]
        Results: list = await gather(*Tasks, return_exceptions=False)
        for result in Results:
            assert result == 200

async def main():
    await GetUrls()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(main())
```

Result of `Results`:

```
200
200
200
200
```

It's checking the URLs in parallel.

Comment: The advantage of using those libraries would then be that I can run the checks in parallel multithreading? Thank you!

Comment: @RobertAlexander Yes exactly. :)

Answer (score 1):

To optimize network usage, add a timeout parameter to the get request to limit the wait time for a response and a stream parameter to the get request to only download a portion of the response in chunks rather than the entire file.

To handle a slow/dead link, add a timeout parameter to the get request to raise an exception if the response takes too long, and catch and handle exceptions raised by the get request such as TimeoutError, ConnectionError, and HTTPError (e.g. retry, log error)

To validate an RSS stream, use a library like feedparser to parse the response and determine whether it's a valid RSS feed, as well as look for specific elements/attributes in the response (e.g. channel, item, title, link) that are required for an RSS feed.

```
import requests
import feedparser
from requests.exceptions import Timeout, ConnectionError, HTTPError

for rssfeed in RSS_FEEDS:
    try:
        response = requests.get(rssfeed, timeout=5)
        response.raise_for_status()
        feed = feedparser.parse(response.content)
        if not feed.bozo:
            # feed is valid
        else:
            # feed is invalid
    except (Timeout, ConnectionError, HTTPError) as e:
        # handle exceptions here (e.g. retry, log error)
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using this only in a test so maybe I can make it simpler just asserting the intended 200 outcome and let the test fail otherwise.